# Redirect entire site to other url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site which you can access with or without https rule. So, I need to make a redirect to another page. Example:

My website is: `www.google.com` so I can access by the moment as `https://www.google.com` and `http://www.google.com` but I need when you get into my website trough `http` or `https` way you must have to redirect to `www.yahoo.com`.

Besides I need the url redirection too to any subdomain or url which exists in `http://www.google.com` or `https://www.google.com`

How can I do this? I have no found alredy information about it in S.O. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple.  You can use the following Redirect in your htaccess to redirect all requests from your site to the other domain

```
RedirectMatch  301 / http://yahoo.com/
```

Comment: Thanks. But is not working. When I visit  my website with `https` is not redirecting to my other website. I'm in GoDaddy's server.

Comment: The `RedirectMatch` applies to both https and http urls. Do you have any other Rules or Redirects in htaccess that can coflict with this one?

Comment: No, I have one only htaccess file and and pasted on it `RedirectMatch  301 / http://yahoo.com/` but when I visit my website like `https://www.google.com` is not redirecting to `http://yahoo.com`